# NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.String org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(java.io.InputStream, java.nio.charset.Charset)'

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, eclipse-plugin, oomph

I wanted to start a spring boot project recently with eclipse, I always imported zip files in this new laptop and did not get any need to create new projects. Although I already did this multiple times in my previous laptop, I cannot do it right now although I tried looking into all the potential configurations problems:

[this is the exact dialog I get when I try to start the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WifQ0.png)

I don't even know what to look for this problem, I don't think we need apache package to build projects in eclipse, I tried to check if any of the project configurations or eclipse preferences is using this package to get this error, but I didn't find anything, any help is verry much appriciated:

Comment: You appear to have posted the same image no fewer than seven times...

Answer (score 0):

I somehow solved it by updating my software(updated Oomph ) by going into help -- > update software.

any explanations as to why this happened is appriciated, I am very curious.

Comment: We don't know what you solved. All we can see is the same (normal looking) dialog repeated seven times